# How to return Url string from Controller a controller in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please i am trying to generate my Url hyperlink dynamically in my MVC Application.

```
<a href='http://facebook.com/myPage'>Facebook</a>
```

The above link takes me to my facebook home page. I want to be able to change the url later on as the page name is not decided. So i tried

```
<a href='@Url.Action("GetFaceBookLink", "Home")'>Facebook</a>
```

And in my controller

```
 public ActionResult GetFaceBookLink()
        {
            string facebook = repository.SystemSettings.FirstOrDefault().FacebookLink;

            return this.Content(facebook);
        }
```

My string facebook = "http://facebook.com/mypage" . I want to be redicted to my facebook home page as usal. However, when i clicked, it returns the string url in a black pagewithout redirecting .  Please how do i redirect ? how do i achieve this ?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need custom helper

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am confused for the url string is returning . Please any tutorial, link or help with the custom helper ?

Comment: You can create a partial view and use RenderAction to render it on main view

Comment: You can do this as well: ``<a href='@Html.Action("GetFaceBookLink", "Home")'>Facebook</a>``

Comment: Brilliant. It works . But just curious why did Html.Action works and Url does'nt ? I though  because we are dealing with url here so Url.Action should do the trick ?

Comment: url.action ccreates path  controller and action name, added answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Html.Action` helper  here :

`<a href='@Html.Action("GetFaceBookLink", "Home")'>Facebook</a>`

`Url.Action` do not calls action, it generates url using Controller and Action name

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to another site from controller  by

```
public ActionResult GetFaceBookLink() {
return Redirect("http://facebook.com/mypage");
}
```

Comment: But i coudn't use `Redirect("http://facebook.com/mypage")` for my case though.  I got the error Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions," . I am doing this in my Layoutpage . A page body has been rendered already and now a controller returning a redirect , i guess thats why the error. Nonetheless , it's a great solution. Thank you :).

Comment: @NuruSalihu che these url for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056421/why-are-redirect-results-not-allowed-in-child-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-2        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015833/child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions-after-setting-the-sit