# Image not displaying in view page using Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display image in view page but it doesn't display in the browser.
Here is my code:
**MyChat.cshtml**

```
<td>
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Mailbox", new { name = Session["Loginname"].ToString() })" id="photo"/>
</td>
```

**Controller**

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(string name)
{
   byte[] cover = GetImageFromDataBase(name);
   ViewData["image"] = cover;
     if (cover != null)
     {
         return File(cover, "image/jpeg");
     }
     else
     {
           return null;
     }
 }

public byte[] GetImageFromDataBase(string name)
{
   RegisterLogic logic = new RegisterLogic();
   byte[] image = logic.GetImage(name);
   return image;
}
```

The Business logic i used for retrieving the values from SQL server 2008 R2 is as:

```
public byte[] GetImage(string name)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = str;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con.Close();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Picture from InspiniaMessage where UserName='" + name + "'";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            Message m = new Message();           
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Message mn = new Message();
                mn.Picture = (byte[])(dr["Picture"]);
                m.Picture = mn.Picture;             

            }           
            return m.Picture;
            con.Close();
        }
     }
```

I have not got any error but the image not displays in the view.

Comment: see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576699/how-to-return-url-string-from-controller-a-controller-in-mvc-4/29577189#29577189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Url.Action` generates url for action against the controller, it never calls the action, for calling action you will have to use `Html.Action()` helper.

when you write:

`@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")`

it return url as string like this:

```
localhost/Controller/Action
```

Use `Html.Action()` as you want to execute action:

```
<img src="@Html.Action("GetImage", 
                       "Mailbox", 
                      new 
                        { 
                         name = Session["Loginname"].ToString() 
                        })" 
     id="photo"/>
```

Comment: it gives error `Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper`. could you help me on this. how to sort this out.