# How to implement Index and create in the same page on MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am a beginner on **MVC** and I am trying to Create a web app where I want the user to be able to create new items and view them in the same page. 
I am trying to do this by using partial view for the Create Action inside the Index view.

The problem is I am not able to redirect from the child to the Index to update the list after creating new item. And I'm getting this error(**Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.**)

Here is my model

```
 public class Expense
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    //[Required]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

,here are my Index and Create Actions

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Expenses.ToList());
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("Create", new Expense());
        //return View();
    }

    // POST: /Expense/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Title,Amount,ApplicationUserId")] Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            expense.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Expenses.Add(expense);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Here is where The exception is thrown
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And here is my Index view

```html
@model IEnumerable<HomeManager.Models.Expense>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "Expense");}
</p>
```

And here is my Create view

```html
@model HomeManager.Models.Expense

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Expense</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId)
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: You need to show the `Create.cshtml` view as well.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did.

Comment: Cant spot the issue, but [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015833/child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions-after-setting-the-sit) explains the issue.

Comment: I get the exception from the Create Action. exactly this line 
(return RedirectToAction("Index");)

Comment: Have you tried with just Response.Redirect("/Index"); ? Substitute Index with your route.

Comment: OK, Got it now. You need to change `@{ Html.RenderAction("Create", "Expense"); }` to `@{ Html.RenderPartial("Create", "Expense", new Expense()); }` (note you do not need the `Create()` GET method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke There is no RenderPartial takes these arguments. I also Tried RenderPartial("Create", new HomeManager.Models.Expense) it shows the Create form but it doesn't post.

Comment: Yes its `RenderPartial("Create", new Expense())` (lazy cut and paste). You will need to specify the action and controller in the form - `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Expense"))  { ....`

Comment: @MarioLopez I tried Response.Redirect("Expense/Index"); but I get this exception (Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I got confused now. If you explain more I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you html for the form is generating

```
<form action="/Expense/Index" method="post">
```

not `action="/Expense/Create"` as it needs to be. If you put a breakpoint on both the `Index()` GET and `Create(Expense expense)` POST methods, you will see that your hitting both of them when you submit the form.

To solve this, explicitly set the action and controller names in the `BeginForm()` method of the partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Expense"))
```

Note that since your `Create()` GET method is not performing any logic, you can also use

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Create", new Expense()); }
```

in lieu of `RenderAction`

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to display the new records immediately they are created then I suggest you use a Javascript library like Knockout, Angular Js or Ember.

Alternatively if you want to use only MVC then you will need to make an ajax call to a method that returns a partial view of the updated Expense record and place this partial view in your DOM in your view.

Comment: I am sure there is a way to do it without using third-parties, otherwise asp.net-MVC wouldn't be such a great framework.