# Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter, custom-action-filter

I have a _layout load menu as :

```
...
@Html.Action("MenuRole","Menu")
...
```

in Action MenuRole i check session with Action Filter :

```
[CheckSession]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult MenuRole()
{
    ....
    return PartialView("_LoadMenu",menuModel);
//_LoadMenu is partial view to show menurole
}
```

And in Action Filter :

```
public class CheckSession : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var ctx = filterContext.HttpContext;

            //if Session == null => Login page
            if (ctx.Session["Username"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Login" }));

            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

When session timeout, _layout show error in @Html.Action("MenuRole","Menu") : **Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions**

Comment: The message is self explanatory - you cannot use `RedirectToRouteResult()` in a method marked `ChildActionOnly` (which you are doing if `Session["Username"]` is `null`)

Comment: I know it. Would you have it any other way ?

Comment: Your problem comes from here: `new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Login" }));` executed after view already rendered. Probably using `@Url.Action` instead of `@Html.Action` may solve this issue.

Comment: If you want the `RedirectToRouteResult` code, then remove the `ChildActionOnly` attribute. The behavior is expained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015833/child-actions-are-not-allowed-to-perform-redirect-actions-after-setting-the-sit)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : Thanks for reply. But it's not show my menurole .       Stephen Muecke : I removed it, but it's not working !

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `[CheckSession]` attribute. `@Html.Action()` means your calling a child action and you cannot redirect within it as explained in the link above.

Comment: I got it. i must find anther way. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 9):

I had the same exception and I solved it by checking `IsChildAction` like :

```
        //if Session == null => Login page
        if (ctx.Session["Username"] == null && !filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Login" }));
        }
```

that solved me the problem

Comment: This problem is : **my check session attribute can not  be used on child actions**. Thanks for reply !